# Calculating upstream (contributing) area for >10,000 points using Python

Tags: python, dem, rasterio, hydrology

I would like to create polygons of the contributing area for > 10,000 points.
I have all information that I need for this, including a 30m DEM, a river network (LineString geodataframe file) and derived flow direction raster.

[image]

I'm currently using the pyflwdir tool, but this takes around 5 minutes per point.

Has anyone any clues on how to approach this easier and quicker?

This is my current script:

```
with rasterio.open(flwdir_fn, "r") as src:
    flwdir = src.read(1)
    crs = src.crs
    flw = pyflwdir.from_array(
        flwdir,
        ftype="d8",
        transform=src.transform,
        latlon=crs.is_geographic,
        cache=True,
    )

for point in geo_df["geometry"].head():
    x = point.x
    y = point.y
    print(x, y)
    subbasins = flw.basins(xy=(x, y), streams=flw.stream_order() >= 4)
```

Comment: Maybe you could....Populate the points with elevation values.  For every point get the elevation, then reclassify the surface where any lower pixel = NoData and all higher pixels  = 1.  Use the result to mask your flow direction surface.  Proceed with your code with the smaller sized flow dir for each point.